# Are .cshtml (Razor) indexable by Google?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I create new website by MVC5.The pages (.cshtml) in the my website are dynamically generated. I want to know that are pages with .cshtml index able by google crawler?

Comment: Most likely they are, what have you googled to try to find out? Try looking here for an answer-https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513925?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `.cshtml` is never served directly, so in one sense, no they will never be indexed by Google or any other search engine, because they cannot be seen by Google or any other search engine.

However, those `.cshtml` files are utilized by controller actions to return an HTML response. As a result, any route indexed by Google that leads to an action that utilizes one of your `.cshtml` files will allow Google to index the *parsed contents* of that file. This is not the same thing has Google directly indexing the physical file, though.

Answer (score 0):

MVC does not serve `.cshtml` files. It processes them and converts them into plain HTML text output. This makes it possible to be completely compliant with web standards and cross-platform (or not, depending on whether you use the built-in HTML helpers or go out of bounds and out of compliance). This includes, but is not limited to, being able to be indexed by search engines such as Google.

Comment: I don't know about the "completely compliant with web-standards and cross-platform" bit. They are only so if you make them so. If I wanted to, I could create views for days that violated every possible web standard and only worked in Netscape Navigator.

Comment: You're right. Updated my answer.